# PHP Code issue - Posts doesn't appear in Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone please help me review the following WordPress PHP code. This suppose to show 4 media post in a page and it used to work until recently it stopped working and I can only see Title of the section and Read More link. I hope to find some help resolving the issue. Thanks.

```
 <?php elseif( get_row_layout() == 'media_section' ):?>
<section class="beehive-in-media-section text-center">

    <h2>Beehive in the Media </h2>

    <div class="container-medium">
        <div class="media-blocks-wrapper">

            <?php
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
            // the query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'post_type' =>'media_posts',
                'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'lists',
                                    'terms' => 'featured'
                                )
                             ),
            ));
            ?>
            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="media-box-wrapper">
                        <div class="media-box-wrapper-inner">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <span><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span>
                                <p><?php the_title(); ?>
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div> <!-- .media-blocks-wrapper -->
    </div> <!-- container-medium -->

    <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('media_posts') ?>" class="btn btn--medium-2 btn--learnMore inline md-16 mbl-16">Read More</a>
</section>
```

Comment: If you have a specific bug, then that's not a matter for a general code review. Please change your title question to reflect the specific issue.

Comment: `recently it stopped working`...the first thing to do is work out what changed, then. Maybe the code was altered? Maybe something is different in the data? We can't see your environment or your source control history so we don't know.

Comment: I understand that you can't see the environment but i was hopping to see if there is any issue with the code above. Code wasn't changed in anyway nor the data. Logically it should work but I can't say for sure. 

I will change the title to make it more appropirate. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well if the code 100% wasn't changed in any way, then it's very likely the code (or at least the code you have shown us here) isn't the issue, because it wouldn't just magically stop working by itself, without some external factor. Therefore we wouldn't be able to spot anything from looking at the code.